# C++ Comparing files in 2 folders

Tags: c++

I am generating hashes for the contents of two folders. I then want to compare all the hashes, one at a time of folder a to all the contents of folder b.

If they have equal files in each this works ok but I plan on having around 500 files in folder B and maybe 5-10 in folder A. the loop im using at the minute is as follows

```
for (i=0;i<nbfiles1;i++)
{
    printf("file1: %s\n", files1[i]);
    for (j=0;j<nbfiles2;j++)
    {
        printf("    file2: %s\n", files2[j]);
        cs=ph_audio_distance_ber(hashes[i],lens[i],hashes2[j],lens2[j],threshold,block_size,Nc);
        double max_f = 0.0;
        for (index=0;index<Nc;index++)
        {
            if (cs[index] > max_f)
                max_f = cs[index];
        }//end if
        printf("    cs = %f\n", max_f);
    }//end for
}//end for
```

where nbfiles1 is the number of files in folder A
and nbfiles 2 is the number of files in folder B

The loop works fine if there are equal numbers of files in each but if there is an unequal number then it crashes. I know the answer is staring right at me but after 3 hours of looking it hasnt dawned on me where im going wrong.

Comment: Giving the begining of you code might help, there must be some problem on your array initialisation.

Comment: There's nothing intensely obvious (to me at any rate) in the code you've posted - the problem may be elsewhere. Where does it actually crash? Have you try running it with the debugger and seeing where it goes wrong?

Comment: file1: /home/chriss/A/01 The Hollow.mp3
    file2: /home/chriss/B/01 The Package.mp3

    file2: /home/chriss/B/10 Pet.mp3                                                                                                                                 It iterates through the first 11 tracks and then terminates.
    cs = 0.251718
    file2: /home/chriss/B/11 Lullaby.mp3
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
fish: Job 1, “./test  /home/chriss/A /home/chriss/B ” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)

Comment: You could catch the exception and get more information about the error. Put something like `try{ \\your code here } catch(std::exception& e){cout<<e.what();}` around your code.

Answer (score 2):

A std::bad_alloc exception is raised when you don't have enouth memory, or try to allocate an invalid size.
Check your code where memory allocations are done, and show us more if you don't find.